# django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: CustomUser has no field named 'usermanager.CustomUser.full_name'

Tags: django

I am creating a custom user model as follows:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    institution = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [full_name, phone_number]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

It works correctly but when I create superuser, I get the following error

`django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: CustomUser has no field named 'usermanager.CustomUser.full_name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your **`REQUIRED_FIELDS`** attribute is that you need to use strings for the field names, not the actual field instances. Change it to

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name', 'phone_number']
```